# Day(Now) displaying January, 1900?

Tags: excel, vba

For whatever reason, everytime I try to use the Day(Now) function in VBA, it keeps displaying "1/9/1900". The Date function displays correctly, so I'm not sure what the issue here is.

```
Sub Test()

Dim datDay As Date

datDay = Day(Now)
MsgBox datDay

End Sub
```

[Here's an image of the error.](https://ibb.co/93YVw8n)

Comment: If you just want the day, then `Dim datDay As Long` instead of `As Date`.  If you want the full date, just use `Now` by itself, and you can format it with `Format(Now, "YourFormatString")` where the date format you want is the "YourFormatString".  For example, if you just want month and day numbers, then you would use `Format(Now, "MM-dd")`

Comment: In your text you say Date(now), but in your code you say Day(now).  Day returns the day of the month, but you are assigning it to a date field... doesn't seem likely to work, but Excel isn't a primary language for me.

Comment: That worked a charm! Could you repost this as an answer so I can resolve the question? Also, why does VBA break when I define it as a Date rather than Long?

Comment: Also, @Bill K, thank you for the catch! That was a typing error on my part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Day` will be an integer somewhere between 1 and 31, depending on, well, the "day" part of the date returned by the `DateTime.Now` function.

The way dates are stored, they're essentially `Double` values, with the integer part being a number of days, and the decimal part being the time of day.

```
Debug.Print Format(CDate(0), "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

Output: `1899-12-30`

We are June 10th, so the date value of `10` corresponds to January 9, 1900.

You want to store the value returned by `Day`, `Month`, and `Year` functions, into `Long` integer variables; not `Date`.

```
Dim datDay As Long
datDay = DateTime.Day(DateTime.Date) ' datDay is 10 because DateTime.Date is 2019-06-10.
```

Note: while unqualified `Day`, `Date`, `Month`, and `Year` (and others) functions work perfectly fine, it's probably a good idea to qualify them with the module they are declared in (`VBA.DateTime`), to avoid potentially confusing ambiguities, e.g. `Date` is both the name of a property of the `DateTime` module, *and* it's also a data type (`Dim foo As Date`), and the two have very different meanings.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim datDay As Date

    datDay = Date

    MsgBox "Whole date: " & datDay & vbNewLine & _
            "Month: " & Month(Date) & " (" & Format(Date, "mmmm") & ")" & vbNewLine & _
            "Day: " & Day(Date) & " (" & Format(Date, "dddd") & ")"

End Sub
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: That works perfectly, except that I need to isolate the day number (and the month) itself.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
    datDay = Day(Now)
```

with

```
    datDay = Day(Now())
```

Not sure if this will fix the problem, but `=Day(Now())` works correctly when typed directly into a cell.

Your problem is `datDay` is typed as a Date. `=Day(Now())` returns just 10, as today is June 10th. As a full Date value, this is 1/10/1900, since Excel indexes day 0 as 1/0/1900.

Comment: Excel isn't VBA, VBA isn't Excel. Excel's day 0 has no bearing on VBA's day 0, and the two happen to be different. Excel's value for day 0 is a work-around for maintaining backward compatibility with a date bug in Lotus-123; VBA doesn't have that.